# nar-maven-plugin - cross compile JNI for arm linux on amd64 linux

Tags: java, c++, linux, maven, maven-nar-plugin

I would cross compile my JNI NAR project to arm linux. On this [link](https://github.com/maven-nar/nar-maven-plugin/wiki/Compiling-for-multiple-platforms), I read the recommendation for compiling on the native systems with help of Jenkins. But I need only compiling for linux and the architectures arm, x86 and AMD64. For this case the using of Jenkis is many overhead (my opinion). Its today possible to cross compile my case on a linux AMD64 machine with the nar plugin? If the answer yes, has anyone an example pom?

Best regards

Comment: I don't have an answer, but +1 to the question. I would love for someone to contribute a working cross-compilation example of this sort to the NAR documentation!